# How to configure and connect a IEEE 802.1X EAP-TLS wireless network with ConnMan on Debian 10?

Tags: linux, tls, networkmanager

I want to connect with ConnMan on a Debian 10 Mate to a hidden wireless network that uses IEEE 802.1X EAP-TLS. I know his SSID. I have a .p12 extension certificate. I can't set the GUI.
So I created the configuration file that ends with .config under `/var/lib/connman`

But I don't know how to do it. I restarted the service but it only appeared once in the GUI but it gave the error **Failure: blocked**. It didn't appear when I rearranged the configuration file and restarted the service.

References:

https://www.mankier.com/5/connman-service.config

http://www.malinov.com/Home/sergey-s-blog/intelgalileo-addingwifi